# Limit to outputted XML Records

Tags: php, xml

I was wondering if there is a way to set a limit to the XML results that are showed?

Like in php/mysql: `SELECT * FROM blablabla ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,44`

But then for stopping the XML Parse after 10 records..

Thnx!

Comment: Which XML parsing library/functions are you using? Is there a loop function you're using?

Comment: Loop yes: foreach($xml as $xmls) { @StevenV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some sort of counter. If you want to leave things in a `foreach` loop:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($xml as $xmls) {
    // do stuff here

    $i++;
    if($i == 10)
        break;
}
```

or if you want to use a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $xmls = $xml[$i];
    // do stuff here
}
```